# Converting HTML formatting to PDF without using external libraries

Tags: android, html, pdf

I'm trying to draw my html formatted string into a pdf file for my android app, but the result is just the non formatted string with all the html tags visible.

Is there a way I can properly format the pdf file without using any external libraries? I can't use any for the app.

Or is there a way to convert an html file to a pdf file?

Comment: Sure there is, read the PDF Specification and write the PDF yourself, it's only about 1300 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can properly format the pdf file without using any external libraries?

Not in any practical sense. If you have a large team or lots of time in which to write your app, you are welcome to write your own PDF generation code, as yms suggests in a comment.

Note that API Level 19+ has some HTML->PDF code in it, for the use in [the printing framework](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html), but it is not designed for generating arbitrary PDF files.

> I can't use any for the app.

Then you cannot write any apps for Android, as every Android app involves libraries. The Android SDK is a library, for example.

Comment: I meant I can't use any third party libraries not the SDK. But thanks.